# How to set control level permissions in a user management module of a website in MVC 4

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have user management module which built in MVC4. My purpose is to set permissions to each users to access controls in webpages of a master website. I don't want to hard code the permission in each web pages of my master website. I exactly want something which works in webforms , the 'Find Control' property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround for this is to get the permissions to client side as Jason data and enable or disable the controls from client side using JS and I am note sure about this. somebody please throw some light on me.